# SSH commands with bash

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a list of servers in a .txt file. Assume that the authorized keys are all in place in the servers.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read server <&3; do #read server names into loop
[[ $server =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]] && continue #prevents a empty line in file
    echo "Name read from file - $server"
    #SSH login
    ssh "$server" 
done 3</home/u0146121/Matt/servers.txt
```

**My questions are...**

Do I ssh correctly? Will this all be non-interactive?

Note - I would try this out on the servers but I don't have access to them yet and I want to get my syntax right before hand. I am a beginner in bash and ssh.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have "empty" lines in your file, or add `[[ $server =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]] && continue` just below the `while` line, so as not to run `ssh` with an empty argument.

Comment: Written like that, `ssh` won't be non-interactive. You need to pipe the commands to the remote shell: for example `echo -ne "date\nwhoami\n" | ssh $server` will execute the `date` and `whoami` commands on `$server`, display the results locally, then close the connection. For longer scripts, use a "here-doc".

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf thanks that's a great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/3872762/678611

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hey @Luke :) I was not sure if it was ssh or bash he'd had help with. If it is bash he needed help to, then I believe that he should had put his question on stackoverflow and then I would be able to help him fully. I am sorry if i am wrong :(

Comment: I did not open the link, but the comment I posted is an automatic response. The point of the StackExchange network though is to be the one place to get information, not click here, click there, click up here, down there, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> ssh "$server"

command in this line is interactive. Use something like:

> ssh $server "uname -a; date"

it will login to server, execute there `uname -a` then `date`, disconnect from server and continue script execution.